# Can I attach a deck to a floating slab house?

Tags: deck, porch

My house is on an insulated floating slab with 16" deep footings around the edges. I want to attach a deck with a roof to the house. The deck will be at ground level. Frost level is 48". Do I float the deck or set the posts below frost?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Usually if you attached two things together, you want them to both move or both not move.

Comment: The frost line is 48" yet your house footings are only 16" deep? That... doesn't sound right.

Comment: That's how an insulated floating slab works, @FreeMan - But it only works for heated buildings AFAIK, so connecting the deck and building would be unwise.

Comment: OK, @Ecnerwal. I'll trust you on that. Sounds odd to me, but I certainly don't knowitall.

Comment: See an example/explanation here: https://www.finehomebuilding.com/2010/11/11/frost-protected-shallow-foundations-2

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Not quite sure about for only heated buildings.  Have a steel(with engineer drawings) quonset style barn/outbuilding built the same way, but without the insulated slab(plain slab).

Comment: Thank you everyone. @crip659 I was thing that the deck should also float with the house. Thank you for confirming that.